# Apache DocumentRoot in URL path. Why?

Tags: apache2, skin

The skin folder on my site is showing the full document root. How do I prevent this?

http://dev.cshardware.net/var/www/html/magento/skin/frontend/enterprise/wood/css/jqtransform.css

Answer (score 0):

looks like permission issue

try to change /var/www/html/magento/media folder permissions so that a user apache process is running under has write permission to it:

```
chown -R apache_user media
find media/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \
find media/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
```

see this http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html